# Non-cyclic subgroup of order 4 in non-dihedral group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

> A group $G$ has sixteen elements:
>
> $$\{e, r, r^2, \dots , r^7, s, rs, r^2s, \dots , r^7s\},$$
>
> where $r$ and $s$ satisfy the relations $r^8 = e, s^2 = e, sr = r^3s$.
> (Note that $G$ is not a dihedral group.)
>
> a) Make a list of the cyclic subgroups of $G$. Make sure to state the elements of each cyclic subgroup, and do not list any subgroup more than once.
>
> b) The group $G$ has two subgroups of order $4$ which are not cyclic.
> State the elements of each of these subgroups.

I have managed to answer part a) and for part b) I have found the klein group, $\{e, r^4, s, r^4s\}$ but I can't find the second group of order $4$, could someone please help with this? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You could check in GAP so you can see what to aim for.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: I believe this is the semidihedral group of order $16$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Since you "have managed to answer part a)", please include that answer to your post. It will be of great help to answer part b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G=\{e,r,r^2,...,r^7,s,rs,...,r^7s\}$
and condition $sr=r^3s \Rightarrow$ $sr^n=r^3sr^{n-1}=...=r^{3n}s$
we can calculate all element order
$|r| = |r^3| = |r^5| = |r^7| = 8$
$|r^2| = |r^6| = |rs| = |r^3s| = |r^5s| = |r^7s| = 4$
$|r^4| = |s| = |r^2s| = |r^4s| = |r^6s| = 2$
and $|e| = 1$
all non-cyclic order-4 group element is in $\{e, r^4, s, r^2s, r^4s, r^6s\}$
simple calculate we can  found other non-cyclic order-4 group is
$\{e, r^2s, r^4, r^6s\}$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Find all elements of order two. Take two of them, $a,b$. Then if $ab=ba$, then $\{ e, a, b, ab\}$ is one such subgroup.

Comment: (+1) Indeed. And the asker already knows the elements of order $2$ (since this is part of question a which they solved), so they don't need more calculations: they just have to check whether $ab$ (or equivalently $ba$) also belongs to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$\{e, r^2s, r^4, r^6s\}.$$