# Using combinational group theoretical perspective on semidirect products, show $\langle r,s\mid r^8, s^2, srs=r^3\rangle$ has two Klein four subgroups

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, group-presentation, semidirect-product, combinatorial-group-theory

*Note: This is an [alternative-proof](/questions/tagged/alternative-proof) question, since I know how to prove the result but I'm asking for a **particular kind** of proof. Why? For the fun of it!*

### Motivation:

I've been trying to give a reason behind the statement in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4879328/104041) from a particular perspective.

### The Question:

> Why, from a combinational group theoretical perspective on semidirect products, does the group $G$ given by
>
> $$P=\langle r,s\mid r^8, s^2, srs=r^3\rangle$$
>
> have two subgroups isomorphic to the Klein group?

*Note: I separated $G$ from $P$ in my notation on purpose, just in case.*

### Thoughts:

By a standard result in combinatorial group theory, the group can be written as

$$\begin{align}
G&\cong\langle r\mid r^8\rangle\rtimes_\varphi\langle s\mid s^2\rangle\\
&\cong \Bbb Z_8\rtimes_\varphi \Bbb Z_2,
\end{align}$$

where $\varphi:\Bbb Z_2\to \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_8)$ is given by $\varphi(s)(r)=r^3$.

---

Are the two simply conjugate to each other?

---

According to [GroupNames](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/1/SD16.html), there is at least one other way to write $G$ as a semidirect product. I would be happy using something other than the one above.

---

That's as far as I got.

Comment: When you ask "are the two simply conjugate", it's not clear which two you mean.  You've shown the presentation for one I think, if I'm reading it correctly, and not sure why you have both names $P,G$ for the same group?

Comment: You really should not mix the two notations for presentations. Either you list equations that hold, or you list elements that will be trivial in the group. E.g. the dihedral group should be either $\langle r,s\mid r^4, s^2, srsr\rangle$, or $\langle r,s\mid r^4=s^2=1, sr=r^{-1}s\rangle$. Not a mix like you are doing, with "$r^8,s^2, sr=r^3s$"

Comment: By "the two", I mean the two subgroups isomorphic to the Klein group. Also, a presentation and its group are different things, @DanielDonnelly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what's being asked, but you have a normal form $sr^k$ for elements in your group, via the last relation:
\begin{equation*}
r^ks = sr^{3k}
\end{equation*}
For such an element to have order $2$ you need
\begin{equation*}
1=(sr^k)(sr^k) = (sr^ks)r^k = r^{4k}
\end{equation*}
So besides the central element $r^4$, there are four elements of order $2$: $\{sr^2, sr^4, sr^6, s\}$. That's enough for 2 Klein subgroups:
\begin{align*}
K_1 &= \{ 1, s, r^4, sr^4\}\\
K_2 &= \{ 1, sr^2, r^4, sr^6\}
\end{align*}
And these are conjugate: $r^{-1}K_1r=K_2$.

Answer (score 2):

It can also be written as $C_4\rtimes (C_2)^2.$

That makes it clear that there's at least two Klein four subgroups,  because  the $(C_2)^2$ is not normal.

So they should be conjugate.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Every element of order $4$ squares to $r^4$, and every Klein subgroup contains $r^4$, so they cannot intersect trivially?